# php session and htaccess to protect images folder not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to protect images folder from public direct access with url to the images, i am using htaccess and php session to check if the users is log-in, if yes it will allow the access to images folder else it will reject the access.

Images folder is not accessible and working now :
example.com/dealer/search/welcome/images

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (!filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) exit();
$file = $_SERVER["/images/.htaccess"].'/YOUR_IMAGE_FOLDER/.htaccess';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= "allow from ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']." #".$_SESSION['id']."\n";
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

Php session:

```
 <?php 
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","demo");
// ob_start(); session_start();
 session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
//header("location:welcome.php");
}
else
{
    header("location:/index.php");
}

?>
```

htaccess:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

However I also have a php script does images search from the images folder above, now the problem is after the search no images are displayed, it showed broken link.

Am i missing anything in my code?

Comment: The way this logic is applied it is going to create more issues than solve any. Writing .htaccess dynamically is going to take more steps than the ones you have mentioned here. For example what happens if one user is already logged in and another one logs in? You append to existing file or just overwrite it? When does the .htaccess gets cleared? etc.

Comment: ok noted, will explore better option to do this, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do this is to disable hotlinking that way anything hotlinking to your images won't work outside of your domain name.

Because as mentioned in the comments on your question maintaining a .htaccess dynamically is going to take much more than that. If userA is logged in and userB logs in than .htaccess gets overwritten by userB's IP and thus userA loses their rights even if they are logged in.

One way to implement this is to just allow access to one particular script on your domain name. Let's say images.php modify .htaccess so they it only allows images to be accessed by this script. And put session validation code on PHP side inside this images.php script.

Comment: Hi Keral, your idea sound good. do you know where can i find more info on allowing htaccess access to php script and put session validation code on php?

Comment: Any .htaccess code that allows only your domain name the access to the images folder will do.